# GetEntryAssembly in VSTest

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .NET Core there is a difference between executing `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` in a simple .NET Core API and executing it when running tests with VSTest.

These are my packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.3.2" />
<PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.3.2" />
```

Here's how I am running a test for an API URL:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task SomeTest()
    {
        var builder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>();
        var testServer = new TestServer(builder);

        var client = testServer.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("someUrl");
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

When `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` is called in a simple .NET Core API it returns the API assembly.
When `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` is called in a test as written above it returns the test package.

I'm not sure if this is by design or not but I need a way to have these return the same thing: the API assembly. I'm using `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly` to iterate over all controllers in the API. I cannot pass the assembly by parameter. Alternatives are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are describing is exactly what `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is supposed to do: See [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly).

Use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` instead: See [Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly).

Alternatively, you can get your API *Assembly* via a **Type** contained in that *Assembly*:

```cs
typeof(MyNamespace.MyClass).Assembly
```

In my opinion, `Type.Assembly` is the more expressive solution: See [Type.Assembly Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assembly).

Comment: If I would use Type.Assembly then I would need to pass some controller as parameter which I cannot do. GetExecutingAssembly is not possible as the executing assembly is not the one containing the controllers. The code which has to iterate over the controllers is in a different assembly.

Comment: @bdebaere, please list the relevant code of the class in which you currently use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`, and outline the dependency hierarchy.